# Inserting elements from query into another database table conditionally

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying two tables that produce the desired results. I need to insert elements conditionally from this results array into another table. Please excuse my lack of understanding, but I am fairly new to php and mysql.

the results fields are: `bus_id, age, race, and sex`.  I want to insert the elements of these fields conditionally into another table that has the fields:  `bus_id, no_people, males, females, and ethnicity%`.

The `bus_id` in results array does = the `bus_id` in the Insert table.

For example I want to count the people that are assigned to a particular `bus_id`, and determine the number of people, how many males, females, and ethnicity %.

My thought process might seem convoluted but please excuse me being a novice. If you could put me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Ok this is the table of results from the query of the first two tables that I have:

```
bus_name bus_id     cus_name    age      race             sex 
 DHL    10          tom selleck      32 asian             male
Fedex   17      jennifer lopez   34 black           female
UPS 1        jet li              26 black            male
UPS 1       hugh douglas         40 black            male
UPS 1        ray lewis           40 white            male
UPS 1       michael vick         38 black            male
UPS 1        ed reed             44 white            male
UPS 1       joe flacco           17 white            male
UPS 1       bob dole             26 latin            male
UPS 1      deion sanders     15 white            male
UPS 1      bill clinton      15 latin            male
UPS 1      lebron james      41 white            male
```

I want to insert these elements conditionally in another table called "comp_struct" that has the following fields:  bus_id, males, females, ethnicity%( possibly will change it to diversity percentages)forget the ethnicity% for now.

So I would like for it look like this once completed.

```
bus_id   no_people     males     females    

  1        10            10        0
  17        1             0        1
  10        1             1        0
```

This is how far I have made it with my code to produce the first table results.

```
$query1 = $db->query("SELECT bus.bus_name, bus.bus_id, bus_users.purch, bus_users.cus_name,  bus_users.age, bus_users.race, bus_users.sex FROM bus, bus_users WHERE bus_users.purch = bus.bus_id ORDER BY bus.bus_name") or die($db->error);


while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
{
(   "SELECT bus_id, 
        COUNT(*), 
        SUM(IF(sex='male', 1, 0)) AS males,
        SUM(IF(sex='female', 1, 0)) AS females
FROM @query1
GROUP BY bus_id



INSERT INTO comp_struct (bus_id, no_people, males, females)
SELECT bus_id, 
        COUNT(*) AS no_people, 
        SUM(IF(sex='male', 1, 0)) AS males,
        SUM(IF(sex='female', 1, 0)) AS females
FROM @query1
GROUP BY bus_id");
```

Needless to say this is not producing the desired results.

Comment: There is a COUNT() function in Mysql which can help you out. You just need to specify right conditions in WHERE clause. Or you can also count them in PHP as well. You need to write some code and then tell us where it is not working.

Comment: I understand that I have to use the count function, but how would I count the result elements that are only assigned to a specific "bus_id", and then insert that answer into another table.

Comment: You can use syntax such as SUM(IF(somefield='female', 1, 0)) instead of COUNT. However could you add the table definitions and sample data and sample results?

Comment: How do you calculate the ethnicity%? Or does bus_id relate to an ethnicity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the ethnicity field for the moment, you can get the values you want with:-

```
SELECT bus_id, 
        COUNT(*), 
        SUM(IF(sex='male', 1, 0)) AS males,
        SUM(IF(sex='female', 1, 0)) AS females
FROM table_one
GROUP BY bus_id
```

and do an insert with:-

```
INSERT INTO table_two(bus_id, no_people, males, females)
SELECT bus_id, 
        COUNT(*) AS no_people, 
        SUM(IF(sex='male', 1, 0)) AS males,
        SUM(IF(sex='female', 1, 0)) AS females
FROM table_one
GROUP BY bus_id
```

EDIT - based on the details you have given now a single statement will do the insert as follows (no need to select the rows separately first)

```
INSERT INTO table_two(bus_id, no_people, males, females)
SELECT bus.bus_id , 
        COUNT(*) AS no_people, 
        SUM(IF(bus_users.sex ='male', 1, 0)) AS males,
        SUM(IF(bus_users.sex ='female', 1, 0)) AS females
FROM bus
INNER JOIN bus_users 
ON bus_users.purch = bus.bus_id 
GROUP BY bus.bus_id
```

EDIT - this gets you the ethnicity as well:-

```
SELECT bus_id, no_people, males, females, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(race, race_percentage, '%'))
FROM
(
    SELECT Sub1.bus_id, Sub2.no_people, Sub2.males, Sub2.females, Sub1.race, (Sub1.race_count / Sub2.no_people) * 100 AS race_percentage
    FROM
    (
        SELECT bus.bus_id , 
                bus_users.race, 
                COUNT(*) AS race_count
        FROM bus
        INNER JOIN bus_users 
        ON bus_users.purch = bus.bus_id 
        GROUP BY bus.bus_id, race
    ) Sub1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT bus.bus_id , 
                COUNT(*) AS no_people, 
                SUM(IF(bus_users.sex ='male', 1, 0)) AS males,
                SUM(IF(bus_users.sex ='female', 1, 0)) AS females
        FROM bus
        INNER JOIN bus_users 
        ON bus_users.purch = bus.bus_id 
        GROUP BY bus.bus_id
    ) Sub2
    ON Sub1.bus_id = Sub2.bus_id
) Sub0
GROUP BY bus_id
```

SQL fiddle here for it:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8c9c/1

Comment: Updated to go with the extra table details